# Cannot access shared folder programatically in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to display shared folder contents in doc library fashion in sharepoint 2007. I am able to get files from local dir `c:\Test` but not from shared folder.

I am using below code to check:

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"\\servername\foldername\"))
```

If I try same code in .net application on same sharepoint server it is detecting the shared folder but no luck with sharepoint code

**it says folder doesn't exist and we are using IIS anonymous with CA Siteminder authentication**

any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you try to access it? Error? Doesn't find it? Attacked by raptors?

Comment: Is your sharepoint site anonymous, windows authentication, kerberos, form authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the IIS application pool of your sharepoint site is configured with a `domain account`; and make sure this account have sufficient rights on the shared folder.

If your app pool is using a local account, you will need to impersonate using `LogonUser (advapi32.dll)`.

Comment: +1 - nothing to do with SharePoint - you are hitting "one hop" behavior of NTLM. Note that making sure that IIS AppPool runs under account with permissions to that shared folder is not enough - you need to revert impersonation to process account or impersonate a user as Sam suggested.

Answer (score -1):

try with Page Viewer Web Part. It's easy to follow the process.